# Are these arithmetics of multiplicative subgroup correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have proven basic things about multiplicative subgroup and I want to make sure whether these are correct.

> Statement1.
>
> Let $\{R_i\}$ be a family of nonzero rings.
>
> Then, $(\prod R_i)^* = \prod (R_i)^*$.

Here, $R^*$ denotes the multiplicative subgroup of a ring $R$.

> Statement 2
>
> Let $S,T$ be nonzero rings.
>
> If $S,T$ are ring isomorphic, then $S^*,T^*$ are group isomorphic.

Are these true?

Comment: Can you prove that a ring isomorphism must take units to units? That would be a good start on the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statements are correct. But please omit the nonzero-assumption, it is not necessary (and in fact misleading since one might think that this enters the proof somewhere, which is not the case). See also [Sexy vacuity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/sexy-vacuity).

For those readers familar with some category theory, here is a quick proof which avoids calculations: The group of units of a ring is a functor $\mathsf{Ring} \to \mathsf{Grp}$, representable by the coalgebra $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$. Every functor preserves isomorphisms (thus, Statement 2) and representable functors preserve limits (thus, Statement 1).